# Sharpe from signal to daily return correlation

Tags: correlation, sharpe-ratio

A few years back in an interview I remember being asked to derive the Sharpe ratio from the correlation between a pre-open daily signal and the open-close returns. I think you had to make some assumptions regarding the risk/reward and accuracy but you could start with a correlation of say 0.05 and back out a sharpe ratio.

I'm interested in revisiting this and can't seem to find anything similar online. Anyone know of any resources?

Update: Happy with comment answer, thanks!

Comment: The 'correlation profile' exercise in [Short Sharpe Course](https://www.ssrn.com/abstract=3036276) does this computation, finding that the Sharpe is approximately equal to the correlation under a 'small angle approximation'.

Comment: Thank you! So we have the optimal allocation being $c \frac{\mu + \rho \sigma f_t}{(\mu + \rho \sigma f_t)^2 + (1 - \rho^2) \sigma^2}$, from the next page I use $c = \rho$ and that's the sharpe? Testing for $\rho = 0.1$, $\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 0.01$, $f_t = 1$, $c = \rho$ gives a sharpe of 1 which seems reasonable. Is that correct?

Comment: $c$ is a positive constant which adjusts the allocation to reach a desired level of volatility. The (optimal) signal-noise ratio is $\zeta_*$ and that's approximately equal to $|\rho|$.

Comment: Okay, so then I'm confused at how to arrive at the Sharpe ratio which shouldn't be scalable.

Comment: It's a small angle approximation, so the Sharpe is only approximately $|\rho|$ when that number is small. That's a reasonable assumption when looking at a daily signal, and the kind of alpha available to mere mortals.

Comment: Ah sorry I see, that's the daily sharpe so $\rho = 0.05$ gives an approximate annual sharpe of $0.8$ which seems in line. Thank you!

Comment: yes indeed. The general equation works for any time scale, but the small angle approximation that gives $\zeta_* \approx |\rho|$ only works when $\rho$ is small, which is typically the case for daily signals and mortal quants.